# How does Kafka Streams work with Partitions that contain incomplete Data?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams engine maps a partition to exactly one worker (i.e. Java App), so that all messages in that partition are processed by that worker.  I have the following scenario, and am trying to understand if it is still feasible for it to work.

I have a Topic A (with 3 partitions).  The messages sent to it are partitioned randomly by Kafka (i.e. there is no key).  The message I send to it has a schema like below

```
{carModel: "Honda", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
```

Since I have 3 partitions, and the messages are partitioned randomly across them, **cars of the same model** could be written to different partitions.  For example

```
P1
{carModel: "Honda", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Honda", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Toyota", color: "Blue", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}

P2
{carModel: "Toyota", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Honda", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Nissan", color: "Blue", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}

P3
{carModel: "Nissan", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Honda", color: "Red", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
{carModel: "Nissan", color: "Blue", timeStampEpoch: 14334343342}
```

Now let's say I wanted to count the **total number of cars seen by carModel**.  I write a Kafka Streams application that listens to topic A, maps messages by carModel, i.e.

```
carStream.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value["carModel"], value))
```

and writes the total to another topic B, a message of the form

```
{carModel: "Nissan", totalCount: 5}
```

I then launch 3 instances of it, all part of the **same Consumer Group**.  Kafka would then efficiently map each partition to one of the workers.  Example

```
P1 --> Worker A
P2 --> Worker B
P3 --> Worker C
```

However, since each Worker only sees 1 partition then it will only see *partial information* for each car model.  It will miss data for the same car model from other partitions.

**Question:  Is my understanding correct?**

If it is, I can imagine that I could re-partition (i.e. reshuffle) my data by carModel for this use case to work.

But I just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding how this works, and in fact Kafka does somehow magically take care of the re-partitioning after my internal mapping in my application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kafka Streams will do the repartitioning of your data automatically. Your program will be something like:

```java
stream.map(...).groupByKey().count();
```

For this pattern, Kafka Streams detects that you set a new key in `map` and thus will create a topic automatically in the background to repartition the data for the `groupByKey().count()` step (as of v0.10.1 via [KAFKA-3561](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3561)).

> Note, `map()` "marks" the stream that it requires repartitioning and `.groupByKey().count()` will create the topic for repartitioning. With this regard, repartitioning is "lazy", i.e., it is only done if required. If there is no `.groupByKey().count()` there would be no repartitioning introduced.

Basically, the program from above is executed in the same way as

```java
stream.map(...).through("some-topic").groupByKey().count();
```

Kafka Streams automatically "insert" the `through()` step and thus computes the correct result.

> If you are using Kafka Streams 0.10.0, you will need to create the repartition topic manually with the desired number of partitions and you will need to add the call to `through()` to your code, too.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I wanted to know.