# How can Kafka Streams perform a join when the data to join could be allocated on different machines?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Having two Kafka topics with two partitions each. Their messages are keyed by the same param id: Integer.

I have two instances of a Kafka Streams application, so each of them would be assigned two partitions (tasks) one per topic.

Now, imagine that the partition having message ids =1 from topic A is assigned to the KStreams app instance A and the partition with message ids =1 from topic B is assigned to app instance B, how can a join of those two KStreams ever work if the data from the topics may not be collocated ( as would happen in this example for keys/ids=1)?

Comment: Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104887/how-does-kafka-streams-work-with-partitions-that-contain-incomplete-data/47109328 -- it works the same way for aggregation and joins. Data will be repartitioned.

Comment: Much clearer now, I appreciate the link Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to do it... if storage is not an issue or frequency if messages are low then you can use the GlobalKtables for one of the topic. It will cost more memory as all the partitions will be synced on all instances of Streams app.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable

Other way is to use the Kafka streams interactive queries to discover the data on other stream instances.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

For KStreams joins - you need to have same number of partitions for both the topics as well as same partitioning strategy. In that way all consumers will read the partitions for both topic in same way.

nice reference Blog for partitioning - https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab

Comment: Then what about joining a KStream with another KStream? It seems pointless if there isn’t any way assure the collocation of the same keys from different topics on the same task https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#join-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.JoinWindows-

Comment: @codependent -you should use the same number of partitions as wells as same partitioning strategy for both topics.. this will ensure that all the consumers get the same partition while reading..                                                     
nice blog on partitioning - https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab

Comment: Hi Aman, this comment answers my question, thanks. If you update your answer with this info I’ll accept it as valid.

Comment: @codependent - glad it answered your question... i have updated the answer with these  details